# Can I deduct an annual state tax (on an LLC) on Form 1040 Schedule C?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040

On [Form 1040 Schedule C - "Profit or Loss From Business (Sole Proprietorship)"](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-c-form-1040)  , the instructions for line 23 ("**taxes and licenses**" under "**Expenses**") have a list of what taxes can and cannot be deducted as expenses. But I can't seem to find an exact match there for an annual state tax (on a disregarded-entity single-owner LLC), neither in the "**you can deduct**" nor in the "**do not deduct**" lists. (For example [this annual state tax - scroll to the **"LLC/Partnership Tax Information"**](https://corp.delaware.gov/paytaxes/) heading.)

So can an annual tax on an LLC be deducted in Schedule C as an expense, or not?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're referring to a "fee" - they indeed name it a "tax" in that document, but for anyone reading it's a "flat fee".  It's not a "state tax" as that phrase is typically used (for example, "Texas has no state tax" or "you pay 7% of your income as state income tax to the state in my state" and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LLC tax falls into the "you can deduct" IRS category here:

> Licenses and regulatory fees for your trade or business paid each year
> to state or local governments.